# Stack items on small device in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am developing a team presentation page for an app with VueJs and Vuetify. I would like the picture and description of each member to be next to each other on desktop, but stacked on top of each other on small displays.

I used `<v-col>` to hold each of the two elements, which gives me what I want on large screens. Is there a canonical way to achieve the stack behaviour on small devices? I am aware of Vuetify breakpoints helpers but don't know how to use them in this case.

[image: illustration of the problem]

Here is the code I used for the components that wraps a person's presentation:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="mb-6">
      <v-col cols="2">
        <v-img :src="member.elements.picture.value[0].url" height="12em"></v-img>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="8">
        <v-container
          class="text-justify body-1"
          v-html="member.elements.description.value"
        ></v-container>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: can you 1) show us what you currently have 2) show a pic of what you want?

Comment: There you go, I tried illustrating it! And I added some of my code as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `v-col` width attribute from `cols` to multiple attributes `lg` and `sm`.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="mb-6">
      <v-col lg="2" sm="12">
        <v-img :src="member.elements.picture.value[0].url" height="12em"></v-img>
      </v-col>
      <v-col lg="8" sm="12">
        <v-container
          class="text-justify body-1"
          v-html="member.elements.description.value"
        ></v-container>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

[grid documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids)